# Creating/Pivoting columns from Rows and Once Pivot created, I want to add values of different columns in the newly created column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pivot, case

[I am not allowed to copy the image, so the below link has the image of INout and Output[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYQq1.png)
[image]

Input:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD 
1          India     DX       100  
2          India      AB       200
3          Aus       DX         300
4          Ger        BC        400
```

Output:

```
ColumnA  India  Aus  Ger  ColumnD
1         DX     -     -    100
2         AB     -      -    200
3         -      DX     -     300
4         -      -      BC     400
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `case` expressions:

```
select columna, 
    case when columnb = 'India' then columnc else '-' end india,
    case when columnb = 'Aus'   then columnc else '-' end aus,
    case when columnb = 'Ger'   then columnc else '-' end ger,
    columnd
from mytable
```

Your sample data does not show it, but you might want to aggregate by `columna`:

```
select columna, 
    coalesce(max(case when columnb = 'India' then columnc end), '-') india,
    coalesce(max(case when columnb = 'Aus'   then columnc end), '-') aus,
    coalesce(max(case when columnb = 'Ger'   then columnc end), '-') ger
from mytable
group by columna
```

Comment: @ GMB, works. Thank You. Is there a way we can dynamically code for more than 50 countries?

Comment: @rockstar: no pb, that was my typo. No, there is no shortuct in pure SQ,  you need to repeat the `max()` expressions to handle more countries.